# Conflicting peer dependency: eslint@8.12.0 @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin@5.16.0

Tags: node.js, npm, eslint

I don't get this, all of the versions seem compatible to me, what am I missing? how do I fix this so I can successfully dedupe? monorepo using npm workspaces. I've been holding back on upgrading to eslint 8 due to intellij incompatablities

```
❯ npm dedupe
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin@5.16.0
npm ERR! Found: eslint@7.32.0
npm ERR! node_modules/eslint
npm ERR!   peer eslint@"*" from @angular-eslint/builder@12.4.1
npm ERR!   node_modules/@angular-eslint/builder
npm ERR!     dev @angular-eslint/builder@"12.4.1" from front-end@0.0.0
npm ERR!     front-end
npm ERR!       front-end@0.0.0
npm ERR!       node_modules/front-end
npm ERR!         workspace front-end from the root project
npm ERR!   peer eslint@"*" from @angular-eslint/eslint-plugin@12.4.1
npm ERR!   node_modules/@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin
npm ERR!     @angular-eslint/eslint-plugin@"12.4.1" from @angular-eslint/schematics@12.4.1
npm ERR!     node_modules/@angular-eslint/schematics
npm ERR!       dev @angular-eslint/schematics@"12.4.1" from front-end@0.0.0
npm ERR!       front-end
npm ERR!         front-end@0.0.0
npm ERR!         node_modules/front-end
npm ERR!     dev @angular-eslint/eslint-plugin@"12.4.1" from front-end@0.0.0
npm ERR!     front-end
npm ERR!       front-end@0.0.0
npm ERR!       node_modules/front-end
npm ERR!         workspace front-end from the root project
npm ERR!   51 more (@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin-template, ...)
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer eslint@"^6.0.0 || ^7.0.0 || ^8.0.0" from @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin@5.16.0
npm ERR! back-end/node_modules/@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin
npm ERR!   dev @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin@"~5.16" from back-end@0.0.0
npm ERR!   back-end
npm ERR!     back-end@0.0.0
npm ERR!     node_modules/back-end
npm ERR!       workspace back-end from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: eslint@8.12.0
npm ERR! node_modules/eslint
npm ERR!   peer eslint@"^6.0.0 || ^7.0.0 || ^8.0.0" from @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin@5.16.0
npm ERR!   back-end/node_modules/@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin
npm ERR!     dev @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin@"~5.16" from back-end@0.0.0
npm ERR!     back-end
npm ERR!       back-end@0.0.0
npm ERR!       node_modules/back-end
npm ERR!         workspace back-end from the root project
```

Comment: same here :(
any success?

Comment: @OrYaacov sorry, no

Comment: I solved my issue! by downgrading "@vue/eslint-config-standard" from  "^6.1.0" to  "^4.0.0" (I recommend delete your node_modules before trying) (and updating my sass-loader, but I don't think that it's related to the issue); Another thing that worth mentioning is that I'm using typescript and I still have "@vue/eslint-config-typescript": "^9.1.0", on my devDependencies.